# How to assign multiple NULL variables in R

Tags: r, shiny

I try to use `purrr::walk()` function to assign multiple NULL variables as following:

```
test <- function() {

  c("a", "b", "c") %>% 
    walk(assign, value = NULL)

  function(x){
    a <<- a + x
    b <<- b + x
    c <<- c + x
    list(a, b, c)
  }

}
```

BUT this does not work. a, b, c are not in the test() function environment.

Comment: Why do you want to assign `NULL` and not `NA` ? What is `x` ?

Comment: Sorry this is not a good example to illustrate my question. a, b here should be tibbes here, and they will be updated later, so I use NULL to assign their original value and use super assign to change them later. test() function here should be a observe function in shiny.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be assigning anything as `c` unless you're trying to override the base function for `c`...

`purrr::walk` is not supposed to return anything so that's probably where your issue is arising.

if you want to vectorize the `assign` function, here's a method using base r:

```
assign_multiple <- Vectorize(assign, vectorize.args = c('x'))
c("a", "b", "c") %>% assign_multiple(value = NULL, envir = environment())
> a
NULL
> b
NULL
> c
NULL
```